# I need to animate my div from off page on the right to the middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

am making a site where jquery is used to slide a div from off of the right side of a site to the middle and when clicked again have it go back. I was able to get it to go from left to middle to back again. In the final I need it to have multiple divs where clicking the first link brings one div and clicking the second brings the first div off screen and the second in its place. I will include what I have here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#toggle').click(function(){
    var hidden = $('.hidden');
    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
      hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    } else {
      hidden.animate({"left":"75px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML structure?

Comment: These are the divs pertaining to above<a href="#" id="toggle"><p>Show/hide Slide Panel</p></a>
<div class="hidden">text goes here !</div>

Comment: So one link for each div I guess

Comment: see my example: http://jsfiddle.net/A3f29/1/ :) byeee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a function like this one :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.toggle').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.hidden').animate({"left":"100%"}, "slow");
    $(this).next('.hidden').animate({"left":"0"}, "slow");
  });
});
```

I use `.toggle` instead of `#toggle` since ID must be unique in the document.

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XAyL3/)**

Answer (score 0):

ID attribute is not supposed to be duplicated. if you have multiple items then use class selectors instead. The following is for one div.

CSS

```
body{overflow:hidden;}
.hidden{position:relative;border:1px solid red;width:6%;left:110%;}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="toggle">Click</a>
<div class="hidden">asds</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#toggle').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    var hidden = $('.hidden');
    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
      hidden.animate({"left":"110%"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    } else {
      hidden.animate({"left":"53%"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
    }
  });
});
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2crgp/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this example I just whipped up will help answer your question. I've posted it on [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/quant/nggp3/) and the code is below. It's not a perfect example, and your mark-up and styling will probably differ, but hopefully it shows a simple yet flexible way to organize the JavaScript. The best way depends on your specific requirements and the tools you have available though.

### HTML

```
<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
<div>
    <div id="first" class="toggleable hidden"></div>
    <div id="second" class="toggleable hidden"></div>
    <div id="third" class="toggleable hidden"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div.toggleable {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    }
div.toggleable.hidden {
    display: none;
    }
div#first {
    background-color: red;
    }
div#second {
    background-color: blue;
    }
div#third {
    background-color: green;
    }
```

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sliderStates = [
        {
            "first": "hide",
            "second": "hide",
            "third": "hide"
        },
        {
            "first": "show",
            "second": "hide",
            "third": "hide"
        },
        {
            "first": "hide",
            "second": "show",
            "third": "hide"
        },
        {
            "first": "hide",
            "second": "hide",
            "third": "show"
        }    
    ];
    var sliderState = 0;

    var incrementState = function() {
        sliderState++;
        if (sliderState >= sliderStates.length)
            sliderState = 1; // Or use 0 if you want to go back to all hidden
    }

    var show = function($div) {
        $div.removeClass("hidden").animate({"left":"75px"}, "slow");
    }

    var hide = function($div) {
        $div.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, function() {
            $div.addClass("hidden");
        });
    }

    var showState = function(state) {
        $.each(["first", "second", "third"], function(index, element) {
            var $div = $("div#" + element);
            if (state[element] === "show")
                show($div);
            else
                hide($div);                
        });
    }

    $('#toggle').click(function() {
        incrementState();
        showState(sliderStates[sliderState]);
    });

});
```